# KnockoutJS Virtual Tag Foreach IE8 appends extra row

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm currently displaying some data with a virtual tag foreach with KnockoutJS 2.1.0 in the following form:

```
<!-- ko foreach:filteredCertificates-->
<div>
  <span data-bind="html:titel">TITEL</span>
  <span data-bind="html:name">NAME</span>
  <span data-bind="html:vorname">VORNAME</span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And `filteredCertificates` looks like this:

```
self.filteredCertificates = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.certifiedEntries(), function(certificate) {
      return certificate.isDeutsch;
    });
}
```

The function doesn't have any errors in any browser.

As you can see, `filteredCertificates` is a `ko.computed()` function that returns an array. In all major browsers, it works perfectly, but in IE8 (surprise) it appends an extra row with no binded data but just the raw content. For instance, the last raw actually has "TITLE", "NAME", and "VORNAME" as the values. I could leave them empty fielded, but that would still append a row even if its content is empty.

I really like using virtual tags, is there a way to fix this without having to use a dom element that wraps the foreach?

Comment: I'd also make sure that you're not running in compatibility mode.

Comment: How is your `filteredCertificates` definied? Can you put together a JSFiddle which demonstrates your issue?

Comment: @nemesv I added the function, not really a brainer. Sadly, it's quite big to put in JSFiddle, but the HTML and JS is the same as here.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging for some time, I realized this phenomenon showed up when IE decides to stop loading your application because it either ran out of patiente or the little small monkeys that plug javascript together decided it was too much work.

The solution is either optimizing your application so the DOM painting doesn't take forever or pray to Paul Irish that your client doesn't use IE8, whatever does the trick.